# How to save FrameworkElement as very large raster image?

Tags: .net, wpf, image, bitmap, frameworkelement

I have to save my [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx) as very large raster image. For now I use the [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653503%28v=vs.90%29) class and a [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619208%28v=vs.90%29), in this way:

```
RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(ElementWidth, ElementHeight, 
     90, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

bmp.Render(MyElement);  // OutOfMemoryException here

PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

using (var stream = File.Create(filePath))
{ encoder.Save(stream); }
```

Where ElementWidth and ElementHeight are large numbers (about 10000x6000). But with this solution there's a OutOfMemoryException when i try to [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.render%28v=vs.90%29) my element.

There are other ways to do what I need (without causing an OutOfMemoryException)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're going to have to render the FrameworkElement in tiles. The easiest way to do this would be to set the [Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip.aspx) property to the position/size of the tile you want to render and then use an instance of a tile-sized RenderTargetBitmap to get that piece on disk. Now you can either

1. Leave the pieces as-is and use them in some sort of [deep-zoom type tiled renderer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128695/Deep-Zoom-for-WPF)
2. Combine them all (note that if they didn't fit in memory to render in the first place, you can't load 'em all to combine, either) using [ImageMagick's command line](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11320)/[large image support](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#tera-pixel) or do it yourself by parsing the file format and then writing the correct output file.

Of course, I don't know if option 2 is of any help because even if you do write the huge output file - how will anyone load it? :)

Hope this helps!